# Example of Markov process not strong Markov

Tags: probability-theory, markov-process

This is again a question about [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246892/why-is-the-following-example-of-a-markov-process-not-strong-markov) (also see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43833/a-markov-process-which-is-not-a-strong-markov-process/43838#43838)).

It seems we can write this process as
$$X_t := \bigl(t - \text{Exp}(1) \mathbf{1}_{\{X_0 = 0\}}\bigr)^+ + \mathbf{1}_{\{X_0 \neq 0 \}}X_0\, .$$

Where $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ is the exponential distribution (CDF: $1-e^{-\lambda x}$) with parameter $\lambda$.

Define the stopping time $\tau := \inf \{ t\geq 0 : X_t > 0\}$.

I've read the following explanation why this is not strong Markov:

$$\mathbf{E}_0 \bigl[f((X_{\tau + t}))|\mathcal{F}_\tau\bigr] = f(t) \neq \int f(y) \kappa_t(0, dy) = e^{-t} f(0) + \int_0^t e^{-s} f(t-s)\, ds\, ,$$

but that makes no sense to me... how can it be $f(t)$? Because $t \in I$ doesn't fit into a function $f\colon E^{\otimes I}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277356/understanding-the-strong-markov-property) for the definition of strong Markov property. For this example $E = [0, \infty)$)...

Comment: Because, in this example, the strong Markov property is already disproven for functions $f$ depending only on a unique random variable $X_{t+\tau}$, not on the whole post-$\tau$ process $(X_{t+\tau})_t$.

Comment: Did you solve your question?